# Show that the index of a normal subgroup is the index of its intersection with a stabilizer in the stabilizer.

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ be a finite group, and suppose it is acting on the finite set $\Omega$. Suppose $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $N$ acts transitively on $\Omega$. Let $\omega \in \Omega$, and let $G_\omega$ be the stabilizer in $G$ of $\omega$. Prove that $|G : N| = |G_\omega: G_\omega \cap N|$.

$\textit{My Attempt:}$ $\ \ $As $N \unlhd G$, $G/N$ forms a well-defined group with coset multiplication. Let $$\mu: G_\omega \longrightarrow G/N$$ be defined by, for $f \in G_\omega$, $\mu(f) = fN$. Suppose $z \in \ker\mu$, so that $zN = \mu(z) = N$, and $\mu \in N$. Thus, $z \in G_\omega \cap N$. If $z \in G_\omega \cap N$, then $z \in N$ so that $\mu(z) = zN = N$, and thus $z \in \ker \mu$. Therefore $\ker\mu = G_\omega \cap N$. By the First Isomorphism Theorem, it suffices to show that $\mu$ is surjective, which is where I am stuck. Suppose $f N \in G/N$. Thus $f \in G$, and $f \cdot \omega \in \Omega$. Since $N$ acts transitively, there is $n \in N$ for which $f \cdot \omega = n \cdot \omega$. I don't know where to go from here. Can I conclude that $f^{-1} \cdot \omega = n^{-1}\cdot \omega$? If so, then I can conclude that $$(fn^{-1}) \cdot \omega = f \cdot (n^{-1} \cdot \omega) = f \cdot (f^{-1} \cdot \omega) = (f f^{-1}) \cdot \omega = e \cdot \omega = \omega$$ so that $fn^{-1} \in G_\omega$ and $\mu(fn^{-1}) = fn^{-1}N = fN$, as $n \in N$ and $N \leq G$ implies $n^{-1} \in N$. Finally, $$G_\omega/ \ker\mu = G_\omega/G_\omega \cap N \cong \mu[G_\omega] = G/N$$ but I doubt I could make the assumption I did just before. I never use the fact that $G$ and $\Omega$ are finite either. I considered perhaps using an argument through Lagrange's Theorem to conclude surjectivity of $\mu$ but didn't know how it would play out. It's likely that my entire approach all together here isn't the right way. Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$G / G_w$ and $N / N_w$ are both bijetive with $\Omega$ because the action is transitive. The bijection comes from the action: send a coset $gG_w$ to $gw$.

($N_w$ is the stabilizer in $w$.)

Now, $N_w = N \cap G_w$, and the result follows by re-arranging these equalities:

$| G : N | = |G| / |N|$, $|G : G_w| = |G| / |G_w|= |N : N_w|= |N|/|N_w|$ and $| G_w : N_w | = |G_w| / |N_w|$.